# post to pages not works after turns app public

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-app-settings

i wrote a very simple function that send some text to a fb app that just post the sended text as post as page where im the admin too.

im using a plugin for laravel that use the longterm fb token as authorization for publish.

unitll now everything works nice, but the post was visible just to me due the developing mode on the app. Today I turn it as pubblic, but i dont works anymore! thats is the error message raised by my plugin:

```
Exception {#323 ▼
  #message: "Graph returned an error: (#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin ▶"
  #code: 0
  #file: "/home/natty/workspace/speechToTextStories/vendor/toolkito/larasap/src/Facebook/Api.php"
  #line: 69
  trace: {▶}
}
```

i didnt change anything on my code, and the "long term token" is still good as fb's debugger says. Maybe I touch something on the settings page of the app, but after i try to put again as before...but no results still erros.

On settings i got:

- publish_pages
- publish_to_groups
- manage_pages

Comment: And did you get those permissions reviewed by Facebook yet …? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: i cant understand sorry, do i need this long review path to acceive a simple task as post as my page? ive seen inside app reviews and they ask me even for a video of each function/permission... is correct?